# Remove Items from Windows Textbox Context Menu in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a Vb.net 2010 and I have created a User Control Text Box which has default Windows Context menu but I have to remove some items from context menu.Items like Right to Left Reading Orders etc. have to remove it and also for that I don't want to create my context menu please keep that in mind.

Comment: with the default context menu your only options are to clear it (which restores it to default context menu), set it to null (no context menu) or disable certain items dynamically: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750420(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-lang=vb. Can I ask why you don't want to create your own?

Comment: I want to use the System Context Menu as per the requirements.

Comment: How can I disable certain items from the system context menu?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.